# "Process is not defined"-error with Polymer and Redux

Tags: redux, polymer

When I try to use Redux with Polymer (lit Element) I got this error:
"Process is not defined ad redux.js".
How to solve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a hack solution from Polymer's PWA Starter kits.

Add this lines to your index.html:

```
<script>
  // HACK(keanulee): The Redux package assumes `process` exists - mock it here before
  // the module is loaded.
  window.process = {
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  };
</script>
```

Works like a charm.